# Why does this str strict comparison fail in Python?

Tags: python, string, comparison

I have this code in a decorator:

```
is_local_valid = ['system_id', 'server_id', 'sensor_id']
local_params = [x for x in is_local_valid if x in kwargs.keys() and kwargs[x].lower() is 'local'] + [y for y in args if y.lower() is 'local']
if local_params == []:
    raise AssertionError("Tried to access the database from a non connected profile")
```

I noticed that the `is` infix operator for comparing two strings returns False in this case, even when `kwargs[x].lower()` equals to `local`. The `==` operator does return True, though. Both are `str`, of course.

Any clue on what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The operators is and is not test for object identity:
>   x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object. x is not y yields the inverse truth value.

```
>>> id('local')
42745112
>>> a = {1: 'locAl'}
>>> id(a[1].lower())
53363408
```

They are not the same object

Comment: Well, that's very 'user friendly', as the Python interpreter optimizes the use of strings by avoiding unnecesary copies only and if only they're not a product of a method.

Comment: @ManuelAbeledo Yes. Actually to fully understand this you should read articles about Python **Data Model**, and learn about `reference counting`.

Answer (score 0):

`a is b` determines whether two names `a` and `b` *reference the same object* (i.e. `id(a) == id(b)`). `a == b` determines whether they *have equal values*. It is rarely a good idea to compare strings with `is`; use `==` instead:

```
>>> "".join("hello")
'hello'
>>> "hello" is "".join("hello")
False
>>> "hello" == "".join("hello")
True
```

The only general case for comparison with `is` would be for `None`, e.g.:

```
if a is None:
```